# How to get the parameter in React using history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am using history.push in React in a specific page inside a function so that once the button is clicked it pushes to a specific page

someFunction (paramToPass) {
    this.props.history.push('/abcfolder/TheFileToReceiveParam',{paramToPass });}

I want to get paramToPass in TheFileToReceiveParam when the page is open but I dont know how to do this.

Would be a big help if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have passed your parameter this way :

```
this.props.history.push('/my-path', { myParam: paramToPass });
```

You can retrieve this parameter using the 'location' property of your destination component:

```
this.props.location.state.myParam;
```

According to the [React Router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location), here's an example of what the location object looks like:

```
{
  key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
  pathname: '/somewhere'
  search: '?some=search-string',
  hash: '#howdy',
  state: {
    [userDefined]: true
  }
}
```